# Get feature while editing

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, pyqgis

I have created my custom form for features editing, using `layer.setEditForm("form.ui")` and `layer.setEditFormInit("init")` properties. `init` method receives `dialog`, `layerId` and `featId` as arguments. Everything works ok, but now I need to get a geometry of a new feature before closing the form.

Is there any way to do it?

Feature id gets assigned to "0" and looks like doesn't exist in the features list before accepting changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in 1.8 due to 0 being a valid id for an existing feature so you can never get the new uncommited feature.  There was a bug report opened in and I fixed it a little while ago.

In the latest dev build (soon 2.0) you are given the full object rather then just the id:

```
def open(dialog, layer, feature):
    geom = feature.geometry()
```

So the only really option to have it work is to run a later build.

Comment: Hi Nathan, thanks for your prompt response. I will try with the latest version then. Do you have any prediction on 2.0 release? I know there is a discussion around it, but maybe you have some fresh updates.

Comment: Meanwhile, does it mean that if I create a couple of new features, it still won't possible to extract them somehow from the layer afterwards, but before calling save on the layer?

Comment: Looks like `layer.setEditForm("form.ui")` doesn't work anymore with the latest buid (1.9.0 b5dc778). I also can't find UI Edit form setting on the layer's properties in QGIS.

Comment: I'll have a look into it.  The UI form settings are now on the Fields tab and you have to change the dropdown at the top left.

Comment: Thanks, found it. Yes, I guess it is a bug. If after assigning editForm in the code I go to the layer's properties (Fields) and select `Attribute editor layout = Provide ui-file` I can see a correct path to the UI form. If I click OK now, to save settings and try to add new features, my form pops up as it was before.